# how to remember username and password in django login using remember_me option in django

Tags: django

I am trying to implement remember me while logging in. I enter my username and password and select the checkbox remember me. Log in is working fine but when I log out, the username and password are not remembered. I implemented the following code. Any solutions?

> views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            remember_me = request.POST.get('remember_me')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user and user.is_superuser:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)

                messages.success(request, 'logged in.')
                return redirect(redirect_url)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, '3home.html', {'form': form})
```

> template

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-signin">
      {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name='username' placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2" name='password' placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mb-20" type="submit">Log in</button>
    <div class="checkbox float-left">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="remember_me" id="basic_checkbox_1" >
    <label for="basic_checkbox_1">Remember me</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

> forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Comment: You can generate and store a cookie in user browser so that next time when he comes back just validate coockie and use it to prefetch username and password

Comment: Just to clarify. Afer you logout the session will be invalidated. So there is no purpose of session to get username and password. What you are trying now is to set session expiry after login which means when you close browser without logout and come back and open it stays logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting session for only not remember condition, have you tried this one

```
if remember_me:
  request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
```

instead of that, although I am not sure but you can try this one

Comment: Try this also if request.POST.get('remember_me', False): 
                         request.session.set_expiry(1209600)